# Center Logo in Menu

Tags: html, css

How do I create this central logo effect for a `position:fixed` menu? Code attempt is below. Is there a better way of doing this via bootstrap or some other framework?

[image]

```css
#menuContainer{position:fixed; width:100%; background-color:red}
#menu img{height:4%; background-color:red; border-radius:100%; padding:5px}
#menu{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="menuContainer">
      <table id="menu">
        <tr>
        <td>left</td>
        <td><img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/headset-icon-83935.png" ></td>
        <td>right</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your attempt seems to be as good as it gets. I don't have enough experience with bootstrap. I know that introducing a layer of javascript to control your CSS also makes your process time technically longer and therefore less efficient, just add a margin-top of the size of the menu to whatever contains the menu and you're golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code, and here is the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gudboisgn/0vgfnp7c/)

css:

```
  #menuContainer{position:fixed; width:100%; background-color:red}
    #menu img{height:4%; background-color:red; border-radius:100%; padding:5px}
    #menu{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}

    #menu .menu-logo img{
      padding:10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background:red;
      margin-bottom:-20px;
    }
```

html:

```
 <div id="menuContainer">
          <table id="menu">
            <tr>
            <td>left</td>
            <td class="menu-logo"><img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/headset-icon-83935.png" ></td>
            <td>right</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```